# How can I make my Form Control variables acessible to classes other than my Form class?

Tags: c#, winforms

For example after creating a new Windows Form project I have my class called Form1.cs and from that form I can simply start typing the name of a form control and it will auto populate the form control variable names and I am able to use them in the class. However I have other classes that need to be able to access these form control variables as well, but they are not accessible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make them public if they are going to be used in another assembly, or internal if they are going to be used in the same project.  Making them static means you don't have to pass your Form1 into the other classes.

Example...  Say your Form1 has a string that contains the text you display in the title bar.  Making it internal static, like this:

```
internal static readonly string MsgBox_Title = " Best Application Evar!";
```

lets you access it from other classes like this:

```
Form1.MsgBox_Title
```

It doesn't have to be readonly; that's just an example I pulled from an old app...

If you don't want static variables, you'll have to pass in an instance of Form1.

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private Form1 m_Form1;

    public SomeClass(Form1 form1)
    {
         m_Form1 = form1;
    }

    private void someMethod()
    {
       string localValue = m_Form1.SomeMemberStringVariable;
    }
}
```

It's a very contrived example, but hopefully you get the idea.

If you want to call the Refresh method from a class instantiated from Form1, you could use an event in the child class to notify Form1.

Example:

This Form1 has a button that I use to show a secondary form.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnShowPopup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PopupForm f = new PopupForm();
        f.CallRefreshHandler += PopupForm_CallRefreshHandler;

        f.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void PopupForm_CallRefreshHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Refresh();
    }
}
```

The secondary form, "PopupForm", has a button that I use to raise an event that the Form1 is subscribed to, and lets Form1 know to call Refresh.

```
public partial class PopupForm : Form
{
    public event EventHandler CallRefreshHandler;

    public PopupForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnRaiseEvent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler handler = CallRefreshHandler;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How about if I wanted to be able to call the Refresh() method without passing the form into the other classes?

Comment: I added an example of raising an event to signal the Form1 to Refresh.

Answer (score 1):

Create an object of that class & start using those variables like this

```
Form1 fm = new Form1();
string  abc = fm.VAR;
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a public property in your form.

```
public string MyProp { get; set; }

Form1 frm = new Form1();
frm.MyProp = "Value";
```

Or define the property as static to avoid having to instantiate Form1:

```
public static string MyProp { get; set; }

Form1.MyProp = "Value";
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue recently.  I was keeping some methods in a separate class.  Maybe not a good design decision in my case, I'm not sure yet.  And these methods sometimes needed to communicate with controls in the main Form1.  For example, to write to textBox1.

Turns out easy enough.  Just write your method signature to include a TextBox instance.  For example you pass textBox1 in and inside the method you refer to it as tb.  Then when you call that method (even though it is in another class) you set the tb.Text property to whatever you like and it will show on textBox1.

This makes sense when you consider that control is just a special kind of object, graphically represented in the Form.  When you pass it as an argument to a method in another class or the same class, you are actually passing the reference.  So writing text to it in the method call will write text to the original control.